# JS can't find HTML select

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I am trying to select the HTML select with javascript. But it seems not to be finding one. 
I have tried a few answers online to that problem, for example:

Wait for the window to fully load:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var opt = document.getElementsByName("productoptions");

    console.log(opt.options);
}
```

And tried to put js after the select element. And yes, I have checked the spelling many times. I would like to know, why that is happening. And every time it is throwing me in the console - undefined.  Maybe you know the answer to that ;)

Current JS code:

```
var opt = document.getElementById("typeselector");
if(opt.value === "DVD")
{
    let furnitures = document.getElementsByClassName("furniture");
    for(let i = 0; i < furnitures.length; i++)
         furnitures[i].style.display = "none";
    let books = document.getElementsByClassName("book");
    for(let i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
         books[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Part of the HTML code, responsible for HTML select part.

```
<div class="iRow">
     <div class="lclass"> 
          <label for="typeselector">Product Category</label> 
     </div>
     <div class="tclass"> 
          <select id="typeselector" name="productoptions">
               <option value="DVD">DVD-Disc</option>
               <option value="Book">Book</option>
               <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByName returns array so use opt[0]

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var opt = document.getElementsByName("productoptions");

    console.log(opt[0].options);
}
```

```html
<div class="iRow">
     <div class="lclass"> 
          <label for="typeselector">Product Category</label> 
     </div>
     <div class="tclass"> 
          <select id="typeselector" name="productoptions">
               <option value="DVD">DVD-Disc</option>
               <option value="Book">Book</option>
               <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, it is finding the element. But how to get the selected element by getElementsByName?

Comment: use console.log(opt[0].options.selectedIndex);

Comment: to print element itself use console.log(opt[0].options[opt[0].options.selectedIndex]);

Comment: But I don't need an element with HTML tags

Comment: You asked to get selected element. To get selected value use console.log(opt[0].options[opt[0].options.selectedIndex].value)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should provide an `onchange` method to select.

```js
var opt = document.getElementById("typeselector");

function handleChange(val){
 alert(opt.value)
 if(opt.value === "DVD")
{
    let furnitures = document.getElementsByClassName("furniture");
    for(let i = 0; i < furnitures.length; i++)
         furnitures[i].style.display = "none";
    let books = document.getElementsByClassName("book");
    for(let i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
         books[i].style.display = "none";
}

}
```

```html
<div class="iRow">
     <div class="lclass"> 
          <label for="typeselector">Product Category</label> 
     </div>
     <div class="tclass"> 
          <select id="typeselector" name="productoptions" onchange="handleChange(this)">
               <option value="DVD">DVD-Disc</option>
               <option value="Book">Book</option>
               <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange enough, it is working here, but not on my site

Comment: If you put the code as it is. It must work :) Check the console for any other errors.

Comment: Additionally check for `onchange="handleChange(this)"`, if you've defined and implemented the function

Comment: Well... It is not throwing any errors in console :D Strange thing...

Comment: @Raitis Do you have a link to your app?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`(document/Element).querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)/[`(document/Element).querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)  to find the options/selected option:

```js
// get options
const options = document.querySelectorAll("#typeselector option");
console.log(Array.from(options).map(v => v.outerHTML).join(","));

// get selected option
const selectedOption = document.querySelector("#typeselector option:checked");
console.log(selectedOption);

// get options (from selector name)
const optionsFromNamedSelector = document.querySelectorAll("[name='productoptions'] option");
console.log([...optionsFromNamedSelector].map(v => v.outerHTML).join(",")); // spread instead of Array.from

// get selected option (from selector name)
const selectedOptionFromNamedSelector = document.querySelector("[name='productoptions'] option:checked");
console.log(selectedOptionFromNamedSelector);

// add handler for change
document.addEventListener("change", evt => {
  if (evt.target.name === "productoptions") {
    const selectedOption = evt.target.querySelector("option:checked");
    console.clear();
    console.log(`You selected: ${selectedOption.textContent} (value: ${selectedOption.value})`);
  }
});
```

```css
body {font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial}
```

```html
<div class="iRow">
     <div class="lclass"> 
          <label for="typeselector">Product Category</label> 
     </div>
     <div class="tclass"> 
          <select id="typeselector" name="productoptions">
               <option value="DVD">DVD-Disc</option>
               <option value="Book">Book</option>
               <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName method returns a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0. In your case, you can access the select element with

```
var opt = document.getElementsByName('productoptions');

console.log('productoptions:', opt[0].options);
```

It is recommended you use the id attribute to handle these kind of things instead of the name attribute as HTML5 has deprecated some of the elements from name attribute.